# WordPress, if function exists and plugin name?

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress theme and have installed some plugins and after reading about including `if(function_exists())` to prevent the site from breaking, how do i determine the name of the functions?

For example i have the plugins; `Contact Form 7`, `Menu Image`, `Gallery` .  How do i find out the function name?;

```
if ( function_exists('$functionname')) {


}
```

Comment: try `is_plugin_active()` function wordpress

Comment: Well, what functions from those plugins are you calling? Generally, you'd protect plugin functions that *your own code calls* using `function_exists()` to stop your code breaking if the plugin is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

you can either look at the specific plugin code, choose a prominent function and use in a code like in your example :

```
if ( function_exists('functionname')) {


}
```

or alternatively, using the [`is_plugin_active()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active) function like demonstrated in the codex :

```
<?php
   If (is_plugin_active('plugin-directory/plugin-file.php')) {
      //plugin is activated
   }
?>
```

Note that the use differs a bit when using in front end , because you need to include a specific file from the backend:

```
<?php include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' ); ?>
<?php is_plugin_active('plugin-directory/plugin-file.php' ?>
```

Please read more in the above codex link.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to do this. The plugins all have their own means of error checking so it's not something to worry about.

If you really want to mess with the plugin code then be aware that it will be overwritten then next time the plugin updates.

Comment: This is really an assumption you should not make . there are A LOT of (really) bad coded and themes plugins out there ..

Comment: I agree, but adding to the plugin code only helps until the next upgrade. The plugins the OP lists do not need this.